# C2440 Can't convert LRESULT to WNDPROC in C++ WinApi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to write this win32 program with WinApi and I'm stuck because the tutorial I'm following seems to have a problem.

MainWindow.h:

```
class MainWindow
{
  public:
    MainWindow(HINSTANCE);
   ~MainWindow(void);

    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

    // [...]
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance) : hwnd(0)
{
  WNDCLASSEX WndClsEx;
  // [...]
  WndClsEx.lpfnWndProc = &MainWindow::WndProcedure;
  // [...]
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindow::WndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  // [...]
}
```

I must be referencing MainWindow::WndProcedure wrong because I'm following the signature exactly as the tutorial says, however the lpfnWndProc line in the constructor gives a compile-time error:

*error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'LRESULT (__stdcall MainWindow::* )(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'WNDPROC'*

Comment: What line are you getting that error on? I don't think it's in what you posted.

Comment: See Raymond Chens [scratch program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx) for the idiomatic way of getting window messages passed to a class method (To answer the next logical question after `static` is added to the method signature).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

replace

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

by

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

The this pointer is a hidden parameter in your function call and by declaring it static the this pointer is not a parameter anymore and the signature of the two functions match.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a non-static member function as a window procedure. If you declare `WndProcedure` as `static` it should compile. A non-member function would work as well.

Non-static member functions have a different signature than static members. This is because they receive an implicit `this` parameter in addition to the explicitly defined parameters.

Answer (score 4):

That's because your WndProcedure function must be either a global function or a **static** member function.