# Error in windows api program: cannot convert from 'LRESULT (__stdcall *)(HWND,UINT,LPARAM,WPARAM) to WNDPROC

Tags: windows, winapi

i've made a simple windows api program having the functions WinMain() and WinProc() , but i'm getting this error :

```
 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'LRESULT (__stdcall *)(HWND,UINT,LPARAM,WPARAM)'    to 'WNDPROC'
 1> This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or function-style cast


  #include<windows.h>

 LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, LPARAM lParam, WPARAM wParam);


 int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
 {
  WNDCLASSEX WindowClass;

  static LPCTSTR szAppName = L"OFWin";
  HWND hWnd;
  MSG msg;

  WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

  WindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
  WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;               // error
          ....
  }

  LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, LPARAM lParam, WPARAM wParam)
  { ..... }
```

the program's taken word to word from my book (ivor horton's beginning visual c++ 2010), what's wrong?

Comment: A search of the error message you posted found this previous question: [C2440 Can't convert LRESULT to WNDPROC in C++ WinApi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318893/c2440-cant-convert-lresult-to-wndproc-in-c-winapi). Please do at least a basic search before asking questions to see if there's already a similar one here; it reduces duplicates and helps keep down clutter. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite - doesn't appear to be a dup of the qu you mention, while they both have the same error message, the circumstances seem quite different: in the other qu, the problem is that the WndProc was a nonstatic class member so needed to be changed to static; that's not the case here (unless the OP is omitting code).

Comment: @BrendanMcK, it certainly appeared to be. Both questions are about the identical error message produced from the same code in the same language (this post mentions C++ in the last sentence); the only thing missing is a reference in the linked post to the book from which the code was was being copied. Honest mistake. :-) (And nice catch, BTW.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, LPARAM lParam, WPARAM wParam);
```

Here's your problem: the LPARAM and WPARAM are backwards, it should be:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

WPARAM and LPARAM have two different types (UINT_PTR and INT_PTR respectively - for historical reasons mostly), so you get a type related error if you accidentally swap them around. Which is a lucky thing in your case: if they were the same type, then instead of getting a compiler error, the code would compile fine, and you'd instead spend some time wondering why your wndproc was apparently getting mixed up parameters passed to it!